# What is the internal sorting technique used in comparator and comparable interfaces and why?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, comparable

With regards to both **Comparable and Comparator interface** in Java, i wanted to ask, what is the **sorting technique used internally**, and any reason for using the sorting technique in comparison to other sort techniques?

Comment: Neither `Comparable` nor `Comparator` do any sorting.

Comment: This will help you to understand the functionality of comparable and comparator [link](http://www.journaldev.com/780/comparable-and-comparator-in-java-example)

Comment: An interface ... is an interface.  It has no "internals".  OK, that's arguably no longer always strictly true in Java 8.  But it is certainly true for `Comparable` and `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

Both `Comparable` and `Comparator` are *interfaces*. All they do is *define a way of asking whether one object is greater than, equal to, or less than another*.

The interfaces don't enforce what that means -- that's up to the class that *implements* the interface. So one `Comparator<Employee>` might say that Adam is "greater than" Bill because A comes before B in the alphabet. Another `Comparator<Employee>` might say that Bill is "greater than" Adam because Bill has been with the company for longer.

Any sort algorithm needs to be able to compare two items, to know which one should come first in the output. If you wrote a bubble sort, you could use `Comparator` to compare items.

Java has built-in sorts in a few places, including `Arrays.sort()`, `Collections.sort()`, `Stream::sorted`.

The JavaDoc for `Arrays` and `Collections` states that:

> The implementation was adapted from Tim Peters's list sort for Python ( TimSort). It uses techiques from Peter McIlroy's "Optimistic Sorting and Information Theoretic Complexity", in Proceedings of the Fourth Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms, pp 467-474, January 1993.

That JavaDoc for `Stream` does not specify the sort method - I suspect this is because implementations are free to vary.